# Volume of a B-rep?

Tags: geometry, volume, brep

I would like to know how to calculate the volume of a solid object that is represented by Boundary representation (B-Rep)? Any hints? Thanks in advance

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/algorithm-for-finding-the-volume-of-a-convex-polytope

Comment: Typically the software that generated the B-Rep object will calculate the volume for you.  So why are you asking the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gauss' theorem to turn the volume integral into a surface integral. You probably remember [Stoke's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem) and [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) from calculus. It's basically the same idea. It is fairly easy to evaluate if you can turn your B-Rep into a set of planar polygons. You can find some details [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=tQn2pILgt9wC&lpg=PA170&dq=area%20of%20planar%20polygons%20and%20volume%20of%20polyhedra%20goldman&pg=PA170#v=onepage&q=area%20of%20planar%20polygons%20and%20volume%20of%20polyhedra%20goldman&f=false) and [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=8CGj9_ZlFKoC&lpg=PA35&dq=area%20of%20planar%20polygons%20and%20volume%20of%20polyhedra%20goldman&pg=PA35#v=onepage&q&f=false).

This isn't going to turn out well if your surface is non-manifold, but the problem isn't well defined in that case anyways.